# How to check if every properties in an object are null

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object, sometimes it is empty like so `{}` other times it will have properties that are set to null.

```
{
  property1: null,
  property2: null
}
```

How can I determine if ALL the properties within this object is null?
If they are all null then return false.

At the moment I'm using lodash to check for the first case where the object is simply `{}` empty. But I also need to cover the second case.

```
if (isEmpty(this.report.device)) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into array and use `every` to check each element. Use `!` to negate the value.

```js
let report = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null,
}

let result = !Object.values(report).every(o => o === null);

console.log(result);
```

An example some elements are not `null`

```js
let report = {
  property1: null,
  property2: 1,
}

let result = !Object.values(report).every(o => o === null);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: what if the object is nested ?

Answer (score 7):

Approach using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function isEmpty (obj) {
    return !Object.values(obj).some(element => element !== null);
}
```

This function (named `isEmpty` to match the name given in the question) shall return `false` if any `obj` property is not `null` and `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Object.keys()` method this will return all keys in that Object as an Array. This makes it possible to do `Object.keys(this.report.device).filter(key => !this.report.device[key] === null)`, which will return you the amount of not null keys, if this is 0 then you have your answer.

In essence relying on `null` properties is not such a good approach it's better to make those properties `undefined` or just to return a flat Object from your API.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple and can be done with a one liner !

```
function IsAllPropertiesNull(obj) {
 return Object.values(obj).every(v=>v == null);
}

a = {'a': null, 'b':null};
var isAllNull = IsAllPropertiesNull(a) 
// isAllNull = true
```

explanation - 
get all values of object - iterate them and check for null

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
let obj = {
   property1: null,
   property2: null,
};

function isEmpty(o) {
  return Object.entries(o).every(([k,v]) => v === null);
}

if(isEmpty(obj)) {
   console.log("Object is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if object has null value for all the keys. One cleaner approach could be.

```js
const set = new Set(Object.values(obj));
const hasOnlyNullValues = set.size === 1 && set.has(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Es2015

```
if (Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e]).every(a => a.length === 0)) {
  console.log('all are empty');
}
```