# Is there a function in Javascript to know if all values in a json object are empty

Tags: javascript, json

If i have a JSON object as below:

`jsonObj = {key1 :"", key2: "", key3:""}`

Is it possible to know that all values are empty using a single function or property of JSON?
I tried `jsonObj.length == 0` & also `!Object.values(jsonObj).length` but that doesnt work.

Comment: That's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if every properties in an object are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619910/how-to-check-if-every-properties-in-an-object-are-null)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well there is no direct way to check ,
But you can check like this :

```
jsonObj = {key1 :"", key2: "", key3:""}
Object.values(jsonObj).every(el=>el.length === 0)
```

Comment: @poojau I think brk provided the same answer minutes before. One-liner-or-not is just the way to write implicit returns in JavaScript arrow functions.

Comment: the solution will return `true` for empty arrays `[]` also, 
if it's expected `Object.values(jsonObj).every(el => !el.length)` more compact

Comment: I just showed what he wanted to know , if you will see his term above he said he tried like `jsonObj.length == 0` ,  thats why i showed with that only , its not about one liner or more obiously it can be written in many ways .

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function but you can use `Object.values` and `every`. Object.values will create an array consisting of object values & `every` will check if all the value in that array pass the test condition

```js
let jsonObj = {
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

let val = Object.values(jsonObj).every((item) => {
  return item === "";
})
console.log(val)
```

Alternatively you can create a function and use `for..in` to iterate the object. If the value of the key is not `""` then return false , else return `true`

```js
function validateObj(obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (obj[keys] !== "") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

let jsonObj = {
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

let jsonObj2 = {
  key1: "123",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

console.log(validateObj(jsonObj));
console.log(validateObj(jsonObj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys()` and check for `.some()` to exit as soon as possible from the loop

```js
const jsonObj = {key1 :"", key2: "", key3:""};
const allValsEmpty = !Object.keys(jsonObj).some(k => jsonObj[k] !== "");

console.log(allValsEmpty) // true
```

basically, as soon the loop encounters a value that is not empty - will stop the iteration.

[Object.keys() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
[Array.prototype.some() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Those double negatives are really hard to reason about — it's not the case that some values are not... `every()` is a better choice.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I must agree, eventually, but since we already have answers providing the `.every()` scenario (that iterates the entire array) - here's just a *hard to reason example* with an early exit - by using `.some()`. If some has value... therefore not all are empty. Am I mistaken something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the property of every value in a JavaScript object is an empty string, then you need to loop over them and test them.

The simplest way to do that is to convert to an array of values and then filter them.

```js
const object = {
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

const array_of_values = Object.values(object);

const array_of_not_empty_strings = array_of_values.filter( value => value !== "" );

if (array_of_not_empty_strings.length) {
    console.log(array_of_not_empty_strings.length + " values were not empty strings");
} else {
    console.log("Every value was an empty string");
}
```

Or more concisely:

```js
const object = {
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

console.log(!!Object.values(object).filter( v => v !== "" ).length);
```